# unset() sendo executado dentro de uma condicional errada

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema interessante: meu unset($_SESSION['x']) está sendo executado dentro de um IF que não é verdadeiro. Vejam meu código:

```
<?php
// Codigo do estado
$cod_estado = $_GET['s'];

// Função da classe Usuario 
$cont_resultado = count(Usuario::CS_GetUsuarios("WHERE cod_estado = " . checarSql($cod_estado)));

// Já tentei < 1, <= 0
if ($cont_resultado == 0) {
    echo "<script>alert('cheguei aqui');</script>"; // So para exemplo
    unset($_SESSION['usuario_estado']);
}
?>
```

Mesmo se `$cont_resultado == 20` ele executa o `unset()` não sei porque.

Função `CS_GetUsuarios()`:

```
public function CS_GetUsuarios($sql_aux = false)
{
    global $obj_conexao;
    $str_sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario $sql_aux";

    $vet_dados = $obj_conexao->query($str_sql)->fetchAll();
    return $vet_dados;
}
```

Vamos supor que eu execute a seguinte query: `SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE cod_estado = 8` e este resultado me retorne no `count` um valor de 20 (uma condicional falsa). Ele vai **não irá** executar o `<script>alert</script>` mas irá executar o `unset()`.

Dando um `var_dump()` antes do IF a **sessão existe**.

- Caso o IF seja verdadeiro (count == 0) a sessão **não irá** existir no fim do script.
- Caso o IF seja falso, ela existirá no fim do script.

O problema todo está quando eu passo para alguma outra página do meu site, a sessão é destruída (mesmo que não tenha entrado no IF).

O estranho é que comentei a linha de `unset($_SESSION['usuario_estado']);` e pronto, os problemas acabaram. A sessão continua existindo mesmo após eu passar para outras páginas.

**Complementando:**
na linha 1 do *index.php* faço um include `include_once "includes/include.php";` que contém as funções principais do meu script.

Arquivo `include.php`:

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set( 'display_errors','1');
//ob_start('ob_gzhandler');

// Header
session_start();

// Daqui para baixo só funções
?>
```

Veja bem, o **include.php** está presente em TODAS as páginas do script pois, todas elas são incluídas através do *index.php*.

O que há de errado?

**UPDATE:**
Apenas para fim de informação, consegui resolver o problema. Minha função `checarSql()` estava passando o `$cod_estado` como string à query, sendo que devia ser um inteiro. Usando assim `Usuario::CS_GetUsuarios("WHERE codEstado = $cod_estado")` obtive êxito.

Comment: Você está removendo o índice em outro lugar ou nesse momento ele não existe.

Comment: Antes do if, verifique se o índice existe com o isset()

Comment: Eu já dei um `var_dump($_SESSION)` antes do IF e a `$_SESSION['usuario_estado']` está lá, é verdadeira.

Comment: Exato. Possivelmente você criou uma falsa verdade achando que é este `unset` que está sendo executado. Não é, senão o `alert` também seria. Ou você chamou o `unset` em outra parte do código, tal como o Rayann disse, ou você está verificando a existência da sessão de forma errada, achando que ela não existe, ou mesmo está criando a sessão de forma errada. Mas com quase toda certeza não é este `unset` o problema.

Comment: E se der depois do `if` ela deixa de existir?

Comment: Anderson, fiz o teste aqui, depois do IF ela deixa de existir, caso entre na condicional lá em cima do `count` for < 0.

Comment: Pode acreditar, não há outro lugar onde está sendo executado algum outro `unset()`. Estou ficando frustrado com isso.

Comment: Dei uma editada com novas informações, talvez ajude.

Comment: Essa informação de que a sessão continua existindo após o `if`, mas não existe em outra página mostra que o problema não é no `if`. Você está utilizando devidamente o `session_start` nesta outra página? Se possível, informe-nos qual é o código desta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59115/discussion-between-anderson-carlos-woss-and-thiago).

Comment: Anderson, adicionei o conteúdo do arquivo onde a session é iniciada.

Comment: Anderson, adicionei um update onde consegui resolver o problema. Obrigado a todos que ajudaram.